# TFS 2017 (Web Portal) - Modify Columns of Child grid on Links tab of a User Story

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I'm trying to look for an option to modify the columns for child links of a user story. I want to add the "Assigned To" column to see who is/was working on this child task.

Here's the screenshot of the web screen I am asking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in option/way to simply add/manage the columns in TFS user story.

However, you could use **work item query** as a workaround to achieve your requirement. There is a **assign to** column of the query result

> We could use "Tree of work items" type of query:
>
> 1. Select "**Tree of work items**"
> 2. Set up the query for the top level work items, 
>      "**User Story**" with id `105` for example here (See below screenshot, just specify the **Parent** work item **ID** here).
> 3. Under "**Filters for linked work items**" you can exclude descendent
>      items, or specify the **Child** work item types, for example only
>      show **Task** and **Bug**, just set `Work Item Type in Task,Bug`, or
>      leave it as **[Any]**, it will returns all the types of child work
>      items for the specific Parent.
> 4. Filter options : **Match top-level work items first**, Type of tree :
>      **Parent/Child**

[image]

The result should be something as below, you could clear see the **Assigned to**column of User Story's child task and know who is/was working on this child task.

[image]